# Conditional regex statment error

Tags: regex

I'm trying to test the conditional regex statements like [on this page](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html) but when I type just a simple example like so `(?(A)X|G)` at [this](https://regex101.com/) great regex testing site it returns me "pattern error".

Comment: The `?` doesn't make sense in that position: what are you trying to match?

Answer (score 0):

> Proposition A Proposition A can be one of several kinds of assertions
>   that the regex engine can test and determine to be true or false.
>   These various kinds of assertions are expressed by small variations in
>   the conditional syntax.

So `A` either need to be replaced by a valid expression, or there should be a capturing group defined by name `A`.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the way conditional regex works.

`(A)` should be something that can be evaluated to true or false. If you want to match `AX` or `.G` you have to use : `^(A)?(?(1)X|G)`.

If there is an `A` at the begining of the string, the group 1 is set then the following character must be `X` else (not an `A`), the following character must be `G`